# Same imports across different files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to include libraries/packages in only one location?

```
class Sample( db.Model ):
  randomText = db.StringProperty( multiline = True )
```

--

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from project.models import Sample
class SampleHandler( ):
  def get( self ):
    xamp = Sample.all( )
```

Since the handler already imports db from the google.appengine.ext library/package, and then imports the model i'd assume you don't have to include it again in the model itself. However, it looks like I have to, any way?

Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import modules *where they are used*.

If your `models` module uses the `google.appengine.ext.db` module, you need to import it there, not in your handler module.

Importing things creates a reference to that 'thing' in your module namespace, so that the code there can find it when using it. `db` is the local name by which you get to use the object defined in `google.appengine.ext`.

If your handler uses the same object, it needs to import that still. If by importing `models` *all names* used by `models` suddenly where available in your handler module too, you'd end up with name conflicts and hard-to-debug errors all over the place.

Vice versa, if only importing `google.appengine.ext.db` in your handler module and not in your `models` module were to work, you'd need to import all the dependencies of given module together with the module itself. This quickly becomes unworkable, as you'd need to document all the things your `models` module requires just to be able to use it.

Comment: So, if "db" is used in both the handler, and the model, i'll have to import them in both? Can't I import all the libraries/packages I use in one file, and then only import that one file, across all files? Edit, does it not work like: <? require_once( 'lib1.php' ); require_once( 'lib2.php' ); require_once( 'lib3.php' ); ?> <? require_once( 'libs.php'); ?> idea

Comment: You can create one module that imports everything, then use `from thatmodule import *` to get everything imported in other places. **This is a bad idea**; you want to be *explicit* about what you import as that creates *clarity* as to what you are using, and from where those things come from.

Comment: So, python simply requires you to import whatever you use, in any script, regardless if one imports an other?

Comment: It does. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find any thing about it